# Country-by-country roll-out from pre-order to release: are pre-ordered users in countries where app isn't immediately available retained?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, release, preorder

What I'm trying to understand is if pre-registered users in regions where the app isn't made available for release immediately would get a notification later when the app is made available for them.

Specifically:

1. Turn off availability in all countries except Canada (so it's not searchable/available anywhere except Canada)
2. Release the app (pre-order -> available for download) -- so that Canadian users get the app.
3. Go back in and turn on availability for other countries when ready -- so that pre-ordered users elsewhere get the notification and it automatically downloads for them.

The main Q is: would pre-ordered users in other countries receive the notification and have the app download on their phones when it's available/released in that country, if it isn't made available immediately at release?

I've tried reaching out to Apple Developer Support & reviewed all the materials they've shared, including on their forum.